# Нужна помощь с clippath

Tags: css, clip-path

```css
section.p7 {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

section.p7 a {
  width: 307px;
  height: 94px;
  line-height: 94px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -153.5px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

section.p7 a:before,
section.p7 a:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
  margin-top: -125px;
}

section.p7 a:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #ffffff;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 80px, 0% 80px, 0% 0);
  transition: all 0.4s 0.25s;
}

section.p7 a:after {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0px, 100% 0px, 100% 0);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

section.p7 a:hover:before {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 80px, 100% 80px, 100% 0);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

section.p7 a:hover:after {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 80px, 100% 80px, 100% 0);
  transition: all 0.5s 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<section class="p7">
  <a href="#">BRIDGEBRIDGEBRIDGE</a>
</section>
```

Нашел такой вот код. Если убрать `margin` у `a`, то мостик становится снизу, а если изменить параметры `top` у псевдо-класса то мостик превращается просто в круг. Как подтянуть его? что-бы он не изменил своего вида? И если слово маленькое то мост сжимается сильно как сделать что бы он масштабировался без изменения внешнего вида?

Answer (score 0):

Искажения происходят из-за того, что у вас комбинируются фиксированные (в пикселах) и динамические (в %) координаты. Можете попробовать переделать их все на проценты или поиграть с css-трансформацией.

Но лучший вариант - не мучаться с рисованием фигурки средствами, которые для этого не предназначены, а отрисовать ее в простейшем векторном редакторе (есть даже онлайн-версии) и сохранить в SVG. Потом эту картинку поставить как `background-image` и вписать в блок со ссылкой по ширине.